# AngularJS. ngRoute против UI-Router

Tags: маршрутизация, шаблоны, ui-router

Для маршрутизации пользовался 'родным' для angular ngRoute. Устраивал пока не нужно было выводить по заданному url два и больше шаблона в двух разных местах одной странички. 
Вот старый код, один шаблон в одном месте `<ng-view>`

```
    .when('/page:page',{
        templateUrl:function(params) {return basePath+'index'+params.page+'.html';},
        controller: 'lessonPageCtrl'
    })
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl:function() {return basePath+'index.html';},
        controller: 'lessonPageCtrl'
    })
```

Пришлось заменить на:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('page', {
        url: 'page:page',
        views: {
            'leftPage': {
                templateUrl: function (stateParams){ return basePath+'indexL'+ stateParams.page + '.html'},
                controller: 'lessonPageCtrl'
            },
            'rightPage': {
                templateUrl: function (stateParams){  return basePath+'indexR'+ stateParams.page + '.html'},
                controller: 'lessonPageCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

Отображается в

```
<div ui-view="leftPage"></div>
<div ui-view="rightPage"></div>
```

Проблема в том что при втором варианте с использованием ui-router `<div ui-view=""></div>` пустые пока не нажать на ссылку `<a ui-sref="page({page: $index})">link</a>` . Что очень плохо. Нужно чтобы вьюха сразу отображалася в зависимости от url как в первом варианте используя nRout. Как решается проблема, что посоветуете?

Comment: в первом варианте у вас настроено два роута, во втором - почему-то один

Comment: А можно работающий фиддл?

Comment: как вариант `ng-view` могли просто на `ng-include` заменить

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/TSZ6R9uposXsk5QckMr7?p=preview не знаю как это поможет. Протэстить можно по url в адресной строке, а тут хз как. При ngRoute когда в адресную строку вставлял например http://example#/page3 урл перехватывалось и загружался контент. А при ui-router пусто пока не нажмешь на ссылку

Comment: Не уверен что ng-include подойдет в данном случае, нужна маршрутизация со всеми вытекающими от сюдого

Answer (score 1):

Кажется решил проблему. В контролере нужно прописать

```
angular
    .module('lessonApp')
    .controller('lessonPageCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
    //..
    var page = $stateParams.page; 
    //..
    $scope.state = $state.current
    $scope.params = $stateParams;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, но проблема, похоже, в url для роута

```
url: 'page:page',
```

если сравните, что было раньше

```
.when('/page:page',{
```

то можно заметить лидирущий `/`

если изменить ваш урл, добавив в него `/`, то можно заметить что планкр, например, работает:

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1WiaBE8xH6l4eBxgX3Kt?p=preview)